# How to parse parenthesis to sum word frequencies in python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, word-frequency

I have an input with words and their frequency for a given line, however, I would like to have a total count of word frequency. I know there are many solutions for calculating word frequency from a file as a whole, but the input I have has brackets around each line, and parenthesis around each word.  I have not been able to extract the word and count because there are a different number of words for each line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

A sample input:

```
     [('Company', 1)]
     [('Tax', 1), ('Service', 1)]
     [('"Birchwood', 1), ('LLC"', 1), ('Enterprise,', 1)]
     [("Wendy's", 1), ('Salon', 1)]
```

Code I have been trying:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def wordCountTotals (fh):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for line in fh:
        word, count = line.split()
        d[word] += count
        return d[word], count
```

I have also tried using :

```
re.search("\((\w+)\, [0-9]+)", s)
```

but still no results

Because there are brackets and parenthesis, this code does not work -  there are too many values to unpack.  If anyone could help with this, I would be so grateful!

Comment: your sample is 4 individual lists.  Did you mean to have a list of lists?

Comment: @roippi - Yes, the sample is separate lists. They correspond to a line in a different file.  The code displayed before would work if each entity was separated by a comma and all in a master list, but my input is a list of lists

Comment: I see, that's what the lines in your file look like.  Yeah, try `literal_eval` as @utdemir suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Your input consists of list of tuples as exactly same syntax in Python, we can use `ast.literal_eval` to exploit this fact.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("     [('Company', 1)]".strip())
[('Company', 1)]
```

So, something along the lines of:

```
d = defaultdict(0)
for line in fh:
    val = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
    for s, c in val:
        d[s] += c
return d
```

would be enough. I have not tried this, might need some fixes.

Comment: I get AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'strip' .  If I can not split the words, I do not see how a word frequency count is possible. Any ideas on what is wrong?